# Scheduler test class error while deploying to Production

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex, deployment-api

Scheduler class:

```
global class Bank implements Database.batchable<sObject> , Database.Stateful{

private EmailTemplate emailTemp;
global Bank(){
    emailTemp = [Select Id From EmailTemplate Where Name = 'Template']; 
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    String query = 'Select Id, Lastname, Firstname, Email From Contact WHERE Account.Premier_partner__c = True AND Account.Name != \'Test Partner\' AND Email != null AND HasOptedOutOfEmail = False';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope){           

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for(Contact con : scope) {
         if(emailTemp != null && con.Email != null && con.Email != '') {
           Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
           email.setToAddresses(new List<String>{con.Email}); 
           email.setTargetObjectId(con.Id);                   
           email.setTemplateId(emailTemp.Id);
           email.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(true);        
           emails.add(email);                                      
        }       
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);                
}   
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
}
}
```

Test Class:

```
@istest(SeeAllData=true)
class Bank_Test{

static testmethod void test() {
    System.Test.startTest();

        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'test';
        a.Company_NMLS_ID__c = '55555';            
        a.recordtypeId = '01239000000EGZp';
        insert a;

        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.Lastname = 'testing1';
        c.Email = 'test@test.com';           
        c.Office_Phone__c = '1234567899';
        c.Contact_NMLS__c = '99852';
        c.title__c = 'Processor';
        c.recordtypeId = '01239000000N6e1';
        insert c;

        // batch test job
        Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new Bank(), 200);

   System.Test.stopTest();
   }
   }
```

I have 100% coverage but when I deploy it to Prod I receive these errors:

> System.UnexpectedException: No more than one executeBatch can be
>   called from within a test method. Please make sure the iterable
>   returned from your start method matches the batch size, resulting in
>   one executeBatch invocation. 
>   Stack Trace: External entry point
>
> System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject
>   Stack Trace: Class.Bank.: line 5, column 1 Class.Bank_Test.test: line 14, column 1

I had deactivated the duplicate rule on Account, contact but I still receive these errors. Thanks!

Thank you guys found the solution, I had modified my Test class to below and there are no issues

```
@isTest
private class Bank_Test{
    static testmethod void test(){

    String query = 'SELECT id, Name FROM Contact' + 'Where Id NOT IN (Select Id, Lastname, Firstname, Email From Contact WHERE Account.Banker__c = True)';
    Contact c = new Contact();
        c.Lastname = 'abc';
        c.Email = 'abc@test.com';           
        c.Office_Phone__c = '1234567899';        
        insert c;

    contact[] con = new List<contact>(); 
    for(Integer i=0;i<0;i++){           
    contact co = new Contact(Lastname = 'abc' +i,Email = 'abc@test.com',Office_Phone__c = '1234567899');
    con.add(co);
    }
    insert con;

    Test.startTest();        
        Database.executeBatch(new Bank(), 200);
    Test.stopTest();

    Integer i = [Select COUNT() from Contact];
    system.assertEquals(i,1);        
    }
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions (:

Comment: First of all its not a good practice to have `@istest(SeeAllData=true) ` and the second error seems to be  because of this line `emailTemp = [Select Id From EmailTemplate Where Name = 'Template'];` there are multiple emailTemplate and you're setting it single object

Comment: If I try to remove `@istest(SeeAllData=true)` it is not covering the code `global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope)`